# NSButtonCell highlighting remains on keypress in Mojave

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton, macos-mojave, nsbuttoncell

I have a class derived from `NSButtonCell` where I draw bezel:

```
override func drawBezel(withFrame frame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        let path = NSBezierPath(bound: frame.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(config.buttonInset), dy: CGFloat(config.buttonInset)), withCorners: corners, withRadius: CGFloat(config.cornerRadius), flip: flipIt)

        path.lineWidth = config.borderWidth
        if(isEnabled)
        {
            if(isHighlighted)
            {
                print("isHighlighted true")
                let fillColor: NSColor = colorMap.buttonHighlightColor
                let strokeColor: NSColor = colorMap.buttonBorderColor
                fillColor.setFill()
                strokeColor.setStroke()
                path.fill()
                path.stroke()
            }
            else
            {
                print("isHighlighted false")
                if(showsStateBy.contains(.changeGrayCellMask))
                {
                    print(".changeGrayCellMask")
                    if(state == .on)
                    {
                        print(".on")
                        let fillColor: NSColor = colorMap.buttonOnColor
                        let strokeColor: NSColor = colorMap.buttonBorderColor
                        fillColor.setFill()
                        strokeColor.setStroke()
                        path.fill()
                        path.stroke()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print(".off")
                        let fillColor: NSColor = colorMap.buttonBackgroundColor
                        let strokeColor: NSColor = colorMap.buttonBorderColor
                        fillColor.setFill()
                        strokeColor.setStroke()
                        path.fill()
                        path.stroke()
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    print("!.changeGrayCellMask")
                    let fillColor: NSColor = colorMap.buttonBackgroundColor
                    let strokeColor: NSColor = colorMap.buttonBorderColor
                    fillColor.setFill()
                    strokeColor.setStroke()
                    path.fill()
                    path.stroke()
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            let fillColor: NSColor = colorMap.buttonBackgroundDisabledColor
            let strokeColor: NSColor = colorMap.buttonBorderColor
            fillColor.setFill()
            strokeColor.setStroke()
            path.fill()
            path.stroke()
        }
    }
```

Additionally I have `keyEquivalent` assigned to the button with my custom cell.

This works perfectly fine either using mouse click or keypress on **macOS High Sierra**. The highlight is shown only when the mouse or key is down.

Log output looks like this:

```
**after click with mouse**
isHighlighted true
isHighlighted false
!.changeGrayCellMask

**after shortcut key**
isHighlighted true
isHighlighted false
!.changeGrayCellMask
```

However, on **Mojave** the behaviour on keypress is different. After keypress the highlighted state remains, while when using mouse, the highlight acts as expected.

The log output from Mojave:

```
**Mojave click with mouse**
isHighlighted true
isHighlighted false
!.changeGrayCellMask

**Mojave after shortcut key**
isHighlighted false
!.changeGrayCellMask
isHighlighted true <----- this is odd
```

So is there something that has been changed in Mojave. As you can see `drawBezel` call order is totally unexpected. Strange thing is why it happens only when using keyboard.

How to achieve button highlight behaviour with keyboard similar to mouse click on Mojave?

**UPDATE**

I was able to create minimal project in XCode Playground demonstrating the problem. You can download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hntdympar1e3n61/HighlightProblem.playground.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Sounds like a bug introduced with Mojave. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Updated with Playground demo project, showing the problem

Comment: set NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance = YES in your info.plist then see what happen

Comment: @RonGahlot, setting that key in info.plist doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the action:

```
[button display];
```

This can be a non elegant solution. But it works for me.